PowerShell Removing Profiles (registry, profile folder, and local account)
I am looking to remove all unused local accounts on all of our computers (400+/-.) I have a script that works for the basic part of removing the 2 local accounts that I'm mainly targeting, but I want to ensure it keeps all domain accounts. Is there a way to add a wildcard to the $AccountsToKeep line that would keep all domain accounts without typing each in? I tried 'DOMAIN*' but that didn't seem to work.
Here's what I'm using (and it seems to work, other than the 'DOMAIN*' part):
$AccountsToKeep = @('administrator','Public','default', 'NetworkService', 'LocalService', 'SystemProfile', 'DOMAIN\*')
Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $PSItem.LastUseTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-0) } | Remove-CimInstance

Remove-Item c:\users\local1 -Recurse -Force
Remove-Item c:\users\local2 -Recurse -Force
net user local1 /delete
net user local2 /delete


I can give you an easy way to find all of the domain accounts based off their SID. Get your domain SID, then filter on that.
$DomainSID = ([security.principal.ntaccount]"$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME").Translate([security.principal.securityidentifier]).AccountDomainSid.Value

Then just filter out for old accounts, special accounts, and accounts that match your domain SID, and everything else can be deleted:
Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LastUseTime -lt ([datetime]::Today) -and !$_.Special -and $_.SID -notmatch $DomainSID } | Remove-CimInstance -whatif

Remove the -WhatIf from the end of that to make it actually delete things.

Use $_.Special -eq $false in the Where-Object clause to prevent needing to specify those "special" accounts in the $AccountsToKeep variable.
Use (Split-Path $_.LocalPath -Leaf) -notin $AccountsToKeep in the Where-Object to omit the accounts which match the last folder part of the user profile folder.
Use (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_) logic to translate the SID values helping identify if they match domain account SID or not.
Remove the -WhatIf from the last line of code in | Remove-CimInstance -WhatIf to run after you test and confirm that this sort of solution will suffice for your need.
PowerShell
$domain = "Domain";
$AccountsToKeep = @('Administrator.machinename','administrator');
$sids = (Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$PSItem.LastUseTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-0) -and $_.Special -eq $false -and (Split-Path $_.LocalPath -Leaf) -notin $AccountsToKeep}).SID;

$NameSidCombo = $sids | ForEach-Object {
    $account = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value;
    If($account -notmatch "$domain\\"){"$($account),$($_)"};
    };

$NameSidCombo;

$NameSidCombo | ForEach-Object { $sid = ($_).Split(",")[1]; Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object {$_.SID -eq $sid} | Remove-CimInstance -WhatIf};

Supporting Resources

ForEach-Object
about_Comparison_Operators

